# JAVA: 2D array simple code but OutOfBounceException

Tags: java, arrays

I am pulling out my hair. This is so simple and i still dont understand why i keep getting an OutOfBounceException. I have simply created an Integer array with length and width of 3. In my eyes this should include positions {0123}{0123}. So p[3][3] should totally be accessible.

PS: I tried to goole and figure this out myself but i cannot seem to figure this out.

```
int[][] p = new int[3][3];
p[3][3] = 3;
System.out.println((p[3][3] == 3));



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at test.main(test.java:3)
```

Comment: Array indexing for an array of size N is like this: 0,1,2,...,N-1.

Comment: Arrays don't act like dictionaries, they don't have keys and values so putting something in position 3 in an empty array just puts it in position one.

Comment: It's not OutOfBounce but ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Brett Jeffreson In Java `int` arrays are given default values of 0. Therefore the array is not empty. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array, in almost every language the size you define is the amount of elements it will then have.

So in say java `int[][] p = new int[3][3];`. Like you said, this will have 3 'rows' and 3 'columns', but you have to index them starting from 0. i.e:

Row1

```
p[0][0]; // column1
p[0][1]; // column2
p[0][2]; // column3
```

Row2

```
p[1][0]; // column1
p[1][1]; // column2
p[1][2]; // column3
```

Row3

```
p[2][0]; // column1
p[2][1]; // column2
p[2][2]; // column3
```

Answer (score -1):

if you declare an index the size does not start at 0, but if you want to access it it starts at 0. therefore max accessible cell is at [2,2] and min is at [0,0]